# CHECK_LIBRARY_EXISTS library with dependencies

Tags: cmake

I'm using cmake to build my c++-project that uses a library that is located in my "/usr/local/bin/" directory.
The relevant part in the CMakeList.txt reads:

```
CHECK_INCLUDE_FILES("/usr/local/include/fann.h" HAVE_FANN_HEADER)
CHECK_LIBRARY_EXISTS(fann fann_get_errno "/usr/local/lib/" HAVE_FANN_LIB)
if(${HAVE_FANN_HEADER} AND ${HAVE_FANN_LIB})
```

the header is found without a problem the while library is not. Looking into the CMakeError.txt shows:

```
`/usr/bin/cc   -DCHECK_FUNCTION_EXISTS=fann_get_errno    CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec2973046031.dir/CheckFunctionExists.c.o  -o cmTryCompileExec2973046031  -L/usr/local/lib -rdynamic -lfann -Wl,-rpath,/usr/local/lib 
/usr/local/lib/libfann.so: undefined reference to 'sin'
/usr/local/lib/libfann.so: undefined reference to 'exp'
/usr/local/lib/libfann.so: undefined reference to 'cos'
/usr/local/lib/libfann.so: undefined reference to 'log'
/usr/local/lib/libfann.so: undefined reference to 'pow'
/usr/local/lib/libfann.so: undefined reference to 'sqrt'
/usr/local/lib/libfann.so: undefined reference to 'floor'`
```

in the subsequent if-statement the second variable is therefore undefined.

I suspect that this is because the test program is not linked with the standard math library. However in my main program the libm.so will be linked.

How do I fix the linking of the cmake test program?

I would be happy about any comments
Thank you

Arne

Comment: Personally, I handle this with using a custom find_package call (http://www.cmake.org/Wiki/CMake:How_To_Find_Libraries) that also will make sure that all the dependencies of Fann are found. An example of this can be found at https://github.com/jrdi/fann-box/blob/master/cmake/FindFANN.cmake (no affiliation, didn't write or try it) but links against math in a linux enviroment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the [documentation of `CHECK_LIBRARY_EXISTS()`](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.1/module/CheckLibraryExists.html), you can set `CMAKE_REQUIRED_LIBRARIES` to a list of libraries required to link the test before invoking `CHECK_LIBRARY_EXISTS()`. Like so:

```
set(CMAKE_REQUIRED_LIBRARIES m)
CHECK_LIBRARY_EXISTS(fann fann_get_errno "/usr/local/lib/" HAVE_FANN_LIB)
```

Comment: Thank you, that was very helpful and fixed the problem

Comment: @AgnesSorr If that's the case, you should mark the answer as accepted (by clicking the green tick mark). It might not be possible immediately, there is a time-out after posting a question (I believe 15 min). And, for the record, it's usually a good idea to read the docs before asking on SO ;-)